# Display purchase note in Woocommerce admin email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I am using a function in my `functions.php` file to display the purchase note for products in Woocommerce customer email. It looks like this:

```
function sww_add_note_woocommerce_emails( $output, $order ) {

    // set a flag so we don't recursively call this filter
    static $run = 0;

    // if we've already run this filter, bail out
    if ( $run ) {
        return $output;
    }

    $args = array(
        'show_purchase_note'    => true,
    );

    // increment our flag so we don't run again
    $run++;

    // if first run, give WooComm our updated table
    return wc_get_email_order_items( $order, $args );
}
add_filter( 'wc_get_email_order_items', 'sww_add_note_woocommerce_emails', 10, 2 );
```

This works perfectly for the email that the customer receives, but I also want it to display the notes in the 'new order' email that admin receives.

They both use the same order table so I'm not sure why it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a hook for [`wc_get_email_order_items`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_email_order_items.html#2567-2603) but a function with some other hooks. Try instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_items_args', 'display_customer_note_in_all_emails', 10, 1 );
function display_customer_note_in_all_emails( $args ) {
    $args['show_purchase_note'] = true;

    return $args;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.